# why does it give error in React Native Touch Id Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

```
unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke Fingerprint.dismiss
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
```

I used react-native-touch-id-android.

When click the Fingerprint button give the error `Could not invoke Fingerprint.isSensorAvailable`

Would you please help?

Comment: Have you properly migrated your project to AndroidX?

Comment: yes .updated to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
my previous version 2.2.3.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Comment: uninstalled the  react-native-touch-id-android and react-native-touch-id .its work fine.
Thanks.